# Performance of concurrent code using dispatch_group_async is MUCH slower than single-threaded version

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I've been doing some experimentation lately on using large numbers of random numbers to generate "normal distribution" bell curves.

The approach is simple:

- Create an array of integers and zero it out. (I'm using 2001 integers)
- Repeatedly calculate indexes in this array and index that entry in the array, as follows

  - Loop either 999 or 1000 times. On each iteration:

    - Seed an array index with the center value (1000)
    - Generate a random number = +1/-1. and add it to the array index
    - at the end of the loop, increment the value at the calculated array index.

Since random values 0/1 tend to occur about as frequently, the end index value from the inner loop above tend to stay close to the center value. Index values much larger/smaller than the starting value are increasingly unusual.

After a large number of repetitions, the values in the array take on the shape of a normal distribution bell curve. However, the high-quality random function arc4random_uniform() that I'm using is fairly slow, and it takes a LOT of iterations to  generate a smooth curve.

I wanted to plot 1,000,000,000 (one billion) points. Running on the main thread, that takes about 16 hours.

I decided to rewrite the calculation code to use dispatch_async, and run it on my 8-core Mac Pro.

I ended up using dispatch_group_async() to submit 8 blocks, with a dispatch_group_notify() to notify the program when all the blocks have finished processing.

For simplicity on the first pass, all 8 blocks write to the same array of NSUInteger values. There is a small chance of a race condition on a read/modify write to one of the array entries, but in that case, that would simply cause one value to be lost. I was planning on adding a lock to the array increment later (or perhaps even creating separate arrays in each block, and then summing them after.)

Anyway, I refactored the code to use dispatch_group_async() and calculate 1/8 of the total values in each block, and set my code off to run. To my utter befuddlement, the concurrent code, while it maxes out all of the cores on my Mac, runs **MUCH** slower than the single-threaded code.

When run on a single thread, I get about 17,800 points plotted per second. When run using dispatch_group_async, the performance drops to more like 665 points/second, or **about 1/26 as fast**. I've varied the number of blocks I submit - 2, 4, or 8, it doesn't matter. Performance is awful. I've also tried simply submitting all 8 blocks using dispatch_async with no dispatch_group. That doesn't matter either.

There's currently no blocking/locking going on: All the blocks run at full speed. I am utterly mystified as to why the concurrent code runs slower.

The code is a little muddled now because I refactored it to work either single-threaded or concurrently so I could test.

Here's the code that runs the calculations:

```
randCount = 2;
#define K_USE_ASYNC 1

#if K_USE_ASYNC
    dispatch_queue_t highQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    //dispatch_group_async

    dispatch_group_t aGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    int totalJobs = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i<totalJobs; i++)
    {
      dispatch_group_async(aGroup,
                           highQ,
                           ^{
                             [self calculateNArrayPoints: KNumberOfEntries /totalJobs
                                          usingRandCount: randCount];
                           });
    }


    dispatch_group_notify(aGroup,
                          dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                          allTasksDoneBlock
                          );
#else
    [self calculateNArrayPoints: KNumberOfEntries
                 usingRandCount: randCount];
    allTasksDoneBlock();
#endif
```

And the common calculation method, which is used by both the single-threaded and the concurrent version:

```
+ (void) calculateNArrayPoints: (NSInteger) pointCount usingRandCount: (int) randCount;
{
  int entry;
  int random_index;

  for (entry =0; entry<pointCount; entry++)
  {
    static int processed = 0;
    if (entry != 0 && entry%100000 == 0)
    {
      [self addTotTotalProcessed: processed];
      processed = 0;
    }

    //Start with a value of 1000 (center value)
    int value = 0;

    //For each entry, add +/- 1 to the value 1000 times.
    int limit  = KPinCount;
    if (randCount==2)
      if (arc4random_uniform(2) !=0)
        limit--;
    for (random_index = 0; random_index<limit; random_index++)
    {
      int random_value = arc4random_uniform(randCount);
      /*
       if 0, value--
       if 1, no change
       if 2, value++
       */
      if (random_value == 0)
        value--;
      else if (random_value == randCount-1)
        value++;
    }
    value += 1000;
    _bellCurveData[value] += 1;
    //printf("\n\nfinal value = %d\n", value);
    processed++;
  }
}
```

This is a quick-and-dirty learning project. It runs on both Mac and iOS, so it uses a shared utilities class. The utilities class is nothing but class methods. There is no instance of the utilities method created. It has an embarrassing number of global variables. If I end up doing anything useful with the code, I'll refactor it to create a utilities singleton, and convert all the globals to instance variables on the singleton.

For now, it works, and the hideous use of globals doesn't affect the outcome, so I'm leaving it.

The code that uses the "processed" variable is just a way of figuring out how many points have been calculated when run in concurrent mode. I added that code after I discovered the horrid performance of the concurrent version, so I'm confident it isn't a cause of the slowdown.

I'm stumped here. I've written a fair amount of concurrent code, and this task is an "[embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)" problem, so there's no reason it shouldn't run at full tilt on all available cores.

Does anybody else see anything that might cause this, or have any other insights to offer?

Comment: If this statement `_bellCurveData[value] += 1;` executes in different threads in parallel you may also suffer from "cache thrashing". See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))

Comment: I would bet that it's cache behavior is decent. The highest activity is going to be on the center indexes in the _bellCurveData array, so those memory locations are going to tend to stay in-cache. Rewriting it so each thread has it's own copy of the array would fix the read/modify/write problem, but at the expense of making cache thrashing more likely, since the total amount of memory/thread would go up.

Comment: If that's the case, then actually, you may suffer even more from cache thrashing. The more _different_ threads access the _same_ memory addresses, the higher the chance of cache thrashing. In order to avoid cache thrashing, give each thread its _own_ memory space, and when all threads finished, sum the result. Even then, you may suffer from even more subtle effects that causes cache thrashing as well that has something to do with the alignment of memory addresses and how caches are organized and implemented on the CPU ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arc4random` uses a critical section while modifying its state. The critical section is super-fast in the non-contended case (when changing from unlocked to locked), but in the contended case (when trying to lock a mutex that's already locked) it has to call the operating system and put the thread to sleep, which decreases performance much.

```
u_int32_t
arc4random()
{
    u_int32_t rnd;

    THREAD_LOCK();
    arc4_check_init();
    arc4_check_stir();
    rnd = arc4_getword(&rs);
    THREAD_UNLOCK();

    return (rnd);
}
```

where `THREAD_LOCK()` is defined as

```
#define THREAD_LOCK()                       \
    do {                            \
        if (__isthreaded)               \
            _pthread_mutex_lock(&arc4random_mtx);   \
    } while (0)
```

Source: [Arc4 random number generator for OpenBSD](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c)

### to make it faster

you could create a `Arc4Random` class that is a wrapper around the static arc4_* functions from arc4random.c . Then you have a random-number generator that is no longer threadsafe, but you could create one generator for each thread.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use Apple's current Libc source code as reference — the one you've linked to is older (I'm guessing you Googled for the arc4random source as well, since that version the first result for me). It's linked in my answer, if that helps. The main difference is that the current implementation uses a spin lock in place of pthreads mutexes.

Comment: @NoelCower hmm, my first thought was "a spinlock wouldn't explain why the multithreaded version is actually many times slower, would it?" So I looked at the assembly. It's true, the lock function used is `libsystem_c.dylib\`_spin_lock$VARIANT$mp` but IMHO it is not a real spinlock, because in the contended case it calls out to the kernel with the `syscall` mnemonic (I'm on the x86-64 platform)

Comment: Hey guys, btw, I made a benchmark before posting the answer. `arc4random()`, executed 100M times on a single thread took 2.7seconds on my macbook. Executing it 2*100M times on two different threads concurrently took 23.5seconds. (wall time in both cases, OSX Mountain Lion, Intel Core i7, Macbook Pro.)

Answer (score 3):

This is speculation, so I can't confirm it one way or another without actually profiling the code (as it goes).

That said, `arc4random` locks for each call, going by [Apple's collection of source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c). Because you're using `arc4random_uniform` potentially across multiple threads, then, you're calling that at least once if not multiple times. So my best guess here is simply that each task is waiting on all other tasks' calls to `arc4random_uniform` (or `_uniform` may be in turn waiting on itself if multiple calls are initiated in parallel and multiple calls to `arc4random` are necessary).

The easiest way to fix this might be to simply pull the existing arc4random.c source code and modify it to either be wrapped in a class while removing synchronization from it (as I suggested in chat, or as Michael suggested) or to make use of thread-local storage (this fixes the thread-safety issue but may be just as slow — haven't tried it myself, so mountain of salt). Bear in mind that if you do go either route, you will need an alternative to accessing `/dev/random` on iOS. I'd recommend using [SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/reference/randomizationreference/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_2) in that case, as it should yield the same or just as good results as reading from `/dev/random` yourself.

So, while I'm pretty sure it's down to `arc4random`, I can't say for sure without profiling because there may be other things causing performance issues even before `arc4random` starts doing its thing.

Comment: I benchmarked it and `arc4random_uniform` is indeed the problem.

Comment: Good to know. Looks like Michael did the same (see his comment on his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Michael and Noel for your  thoughtful responses.

Indeed it seems that arc4random() and arc4random_uniform() use a variant of a spin_lock, and performance is horrible in multi-threaded use.

It makes sense that a spin-lock is a really bad choice in a case where there are a lot of collisions, because a spin-lock causes the thread to block until the lock is released, thus tying up that core.

The ideal would be to create my own version of arc4random that maintains it's own state array in instance variables and is not thread-safe would probably be the best solution. I would then refactor my app to create a separate instance of my random generator for each thread.

However, this is a side-project for my own research. That's more effort than I'm prepared to expend if I'm not getting paid.

As an experiment, I replaced the code with rand(), and the single-threaded case is quite a bit faster, since rand() is a simpler, faster algorithm. The random numbers aren't as good either. From what I've read, rand() has problems with cyclic patterns in the lower bits, so instead of using the typical rand()%2, I used rand()%0x4000 instead, to use the second-to-highest order bit instead.

However, performance still decreased dramatically when I tried to use rand() in my multi-threaded code. It must use locking internally as well.

I then switched to rand_r(), which takes a pointer to a seed value, assuming that since it  is stateless, it probably does not use locking.

Bingo. I now get 415,674 points/second running on my 8-core Mac Pro.