# How to make vector drawing functions more concise in Swift

Tags: swift, vector-graphics, swift5

I made a button to match the style of the rest of my application, however it's too bulky. I tried a few things, but this is as small as I've been able to get it.

```
class ButtonPath {
    private let wiggle: Int = 3
    func points(height: Int) ->
        ((Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int),
         (Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int))
    {
        func rand() -> Int { Int.random(in: -wiggle...wiggle) }
        func r2(x: Int) -> Int { Int.random(in: -x...x) }
        let screen: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let widthMx = CGFloat(0.9)
        let origin = (x:15, y:15)
        let width = Int(screen.width * widthMx)

        // Corner points
        let tl   = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: origin.x + rand()) // tl = Top Left, etc.
        let tr   = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),      y: origin.y + rand())
        let bl   = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let br   = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),      y: origin.y + height + rand())

        // Arc controls, we're drawing a rectangle counter-clockwise from the top left
        let a1c1 = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: Int(Double(origin.y+height+rand()) * 0.3)) // a1c1 = Arc 1 Control 1
        let a1c2 = (x: origin.x + rand(),   y: Int(Double(origin.y+height+rand()) * 0.6))
        let a2c1 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.3), y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let a2c2 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + height + rand())
        let a3c1 = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),                y: Int(Double(origin.y + height+rand()) * 0.6))
        let a3c2 = (x: origin.x + width + rand(),                y: Int(Double(origin.y + height+rand()) * 0.3))
        let a4c1 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + rand())
        let a4c2 = (x: Int(Double(origin.x+width+rand()) * 0.6), y: origin.y + rand())

        return (
            t1: tl, tr: tr, b1: bl, br: br,
            a1c1: a1c1, a1c2: a1c2, a2c1: a2c1,
            a2c2:a2c2, a3c1:a3c1, a3c2:a3c2, a4c1:a4c1, a4c2:a4c2
        )
    }
    func path (height:Int) -> Path {
        let (tl, tr, bl, br, a1c1, a1c2, a2c1, a2c2, a3c1, a3c2, a4c1, a4c2) = points(height: height)
        return Path { path in
            path.move( to: CGPoint(x: tl.0, y: tl.1) )
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: bl.0, y: bl.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a1c1.0, y: a1c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a1c2.0, y: a1c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: br.0, y: br.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a2c1.0, y: a2c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a2c2.0, y: a2c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: tr.0, y: tr.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a3c1.0, y: a3c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a3c2.0, y: a3c2.1))
            path.addCurve( to: CGPoint(x: tl.0-2, y: tl.1), control1: CGPoint(x: a4c1.0, y: a4c1.1), control2: CGPoint(x: a4c2.0, y: a4c2.1))
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a function I could write to output the value of the corners, arcs, paths, etc?

Comment: That is pretty neat code. Sometimes it's best not to shorten it as _much_ as possible, because then it goes back to unreadable.

Comment: "Bulky" is fine, as long as its readable, and maintainable. If you think that you can look back on this in a year and understand what's going on, then that's a good outcome. Personally, I recommend people make shapes using structs, whose functions computed properties give you points of the shape. See this example: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/1ac8e63001bd703cd4e460ba57b4df2f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code in several ways:

- Just use `CGFloat` everywhere instead of constantly converting between `Int` and `Double`.
- Add some `fileprivate` operators for doing math on `CGPoint`. Or add them project-wide if you need them in other files.
- Factor out a method that wiggles a point.
- Factor out a method that draws a wiggly line from the current point to another point.

You're apparently using the [`Path`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path#) type. So I deduce you are using SwiftUI.

SwiftUI has a [`Shape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape) protocol that you might want to use. You conform to the `Shape` protocol by defining a method `path(in frame: CGRect) -> Path`. Since SwiftUI gives you the frame of your `Shape`, you don't have to use a `GeometryReader` to get your shape's size.

Also, since SwiftUI can ask a `View` (including a `Shape` or a `Path`) for its `body` at any time, and as many times as it wants, it's important to make the code deterministic. That means not using the `SystemRandomNumberGenerator`. So let's start by defining a deterministic `RandomNumberGenerator`:

```
struct Xorshift128Plus: RandomNumberGenerator {
    var seed: (UInt64, UInt64)

    mutating func next() -> UInt64 {
        // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385556/77567
        // The state must be seeded so that it is not everywhere zero.
        if seed == (0, 0) { seed = (0, 1) }
        var x = seed.0
        x ^= x << 23
        x ^= x >> 17
        x ^= seed.1
        x ^= seed.1 >> 26
        seed = (seed.1, x)
        return seed.0 &+ seed.1
    }
}
```

We'll also want these arithmetic operators on `CGPoint`:

```
fileprivate func *(s: CGFloat, p: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { .init(x: s * p.x, y: s * p.y) }
fileprivate func +(p: CGPoint, q: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { .init(x: p.x + q.x, y: p.y + q.y) }
fileprivate func -(p: CGPoint, q: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { .init(x: p.x - q.x, y: p.y - q.y) }
```

Now we're ready to implement a method that wiggles a point:

```
extension CGPoint {
    fileprivate func wiggled<RNG: RandomNumberGenerator>(by wiggle: CGFloat, using rng: inout RNG) -> CGPoint {
        return .init(
            x: x + CGFloat.random(in: -wiggle...wiggle, using: &rng),
            y: y + CGFloat.random(in: -wiggle...wiggle, using: &rng))
    }
}
```

Note that we are generic over the `RandomNumberGenerator` type because we take it `inout`. We could hardcode `Xorshift128Plus` or any other concrete implementation of `RandomNumberGenerator` instead of being generic. But why limit ourselves?

With the point wiggler in hand, we can implement an `addWigglyLine` method on `Path`:

```
extension Path {
    fileprivate mutating func addWigglyLine<RNG: RandomNumberGenerator>(
        to p3: CGPoint, wiggle: CGFloat, rng: inout RNG)
    {
        let p0 = currentPoint ?? .zero
        let v = p3 - p0
        let p1 = (p0 + (1/3) * v).wiggled(by: wiggle, using: &rng)
        let p2 = (p0 + (2/3) * v).wiggled(by: wiggle, using: &rng)
        addCurve(to: p3, control1: p1, control2: p2)
    }
}
```

And finally we can implement `WigglyRect`, a custom `Shape`. Again we need to be generic over the `RandomNumberGenerator`. Note that since we need to mention the start/end point twice, we store it wiggled in `p0` so that we can close the path neatly.

```
struct WigglyRect<RNG: RandomNumberGenerator>: Shape {
    var rng: RNG
    var wiggle: CGFloat = 8

    func path(in frame: CGRect) -> Path {
        var rng = self.rng
        func p(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
            return CGPoint(x: x, y: y).wiggled(by: wiggle, using: &rng)
        }

        let rect = frame.insetBy(dx: wiggle, dy: wiggle)
        let (x0, x1, y0, y1) = (rect.minX, rect.maxX, rect.minY, rect.maxY)
        let p0 = p(x0, y0)
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: p0)
        path.addWigglyLine(to: p(x1, y0), wiggle: wiggle, rng: &rng)
        path.addWigglyLine(to: p(x1, y1), wiggle: wiggle, rng: &rng)
        path.addWigglyLine(to: p(x0, y1), wiggle: wiggle, rng: &rng)
        path.addWigglyLine(to: p0, wiggle: wiggle, rng: &rng)
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

I tested on macOS. To use your code, I changed your use of `UIScreen.main.bounds` to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 600)`. Here's the preview code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var seed: (UInt64, UInt64) = makeSeed()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ButtonPath().path(height: 100)
                .stroke()
                .frame(height: 100)
                .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.2))
            WigglyRect(rng: Xorshift128Plus(seed: seed))
                .stroke()
                .frame(height: 100)
                .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.2))
            Spacer()
            Button("Reseed") {
                self.seed = Self.makeSeed()
            }
        } //
            .padding()
    }

    private static func makeSeed() -> (UInt64, UInt64) {
        (UInt64.random(in: .min ... .max), UInt64.random(in: .min ... .max))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width: 300, height: 600))
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: demo of wiggly buttons]

Your code draws the top shape. The code in this answer draws the bottom shape. I put pink backgrounds behind each path, showing the path's frame. Note that your code doesn't make the path conform to its bounds.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a thoughtful answer, Rob. This is exactly what I was hoping for and more. Incredible! Thanks.