# Why is rand() much faster than arc4random()?

Tags: c, random, bsd, arc4random

I'm writing a game AI which requires fast integer random number generation. This game is for Mac OS, so there are two choices `rand()` (the plain C) and `arc4random()` (BSD). I didn't find any comparison in speed for these two functions, so I wrote a small program to test:

```
long i;

// Record timestamp here.
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < 999999999; ++i) {
    rand();
}
// Record timestamp here.
for (i = 0; i < 999999999; ++i) {
    arc4random();
}
// Record timestamp here and print all three.
```

I tested several times. Results are quite stable: `srand()` and 999999999 iterations of `rand()` takes around 6 s, while `arc4random()` takes much longer (around 30 s).

Is there any reason that `arc4random()` takes much longer time? Or is there any flaw in my testing. Thank you!

Comment: They are perhaps using different algorithms?

Comment: Here is detailed answer on your question [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685920/performance-of-concurrent-code-using-dispatch-group-async-is-much-slower-than-si)

Comment: @MotorparkRustavi Oh, thank you! I didn't find the answer if search for why arc4random is slow. So the latency is caused by thread safety, right?

Comment: That's probably only half of it. Also, `rand` itself is veery simple compared to arc4random

Comment: In a game, do you really need a "good" random algorithm? My technique, was to use additional data such as the length of time between the player's keyboard/mouse actions, which practically would be impossible to replicate.

Comment: I seriously doubt that here the culprit is thread safety, given that, at least from what we gather from this question, no threading and contention is involved. It's just that `arc4random()` uses a much more complicated algorithm. If you don't need the "better quality" random numbers it yields you can just use a good old LCG (which is as fast as a PRNGs can get), such as the one from `rand()`. If threading is involved, implement your own LCG and use a separate state for each thread to avoid both contention and race conditions.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You are right. I just wrote a thread unsafe version of `arc4random()`, and call it in a similar testing code. Thread unsafe version runs faster (for sure), 15 s on average. But it is still 2.5 times slower than `rand`. Maybe there is still latency introduced by file io. And yes, the game may not need a very sound randomness, so `rand()` should be enough, or using @weather 's method.

Comment: `rand` and other PRNGs generate a fixed sequence. The user events happen relatively slowly, but if you build their event time into the RNG that will disturb its predictable sequence.

Comment: ARC4 (or RC4) is a cryptographic algorithm.  It trades time for security.  If you don't need the security, which you probably don't for a game, then don't use ARC4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your results are reasonable.**

The two functions are designed for different purposes and they are based on completely different class of pseudorandom number generators.

**`rand()`** is a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG), generally implemented as a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG), which is reasonably fast but generally it has notoriously bad statistical properties.

**`arc4random()`** is a [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (CSPRNG), which is generally slower but also suitable for cryptographical use, which implies it has higher statistical quality of randomness than a PRNG. According to the documentations [here](https://wiki.debian.org/arc4random), [here](http://man.openbsd.org/arc4random) and [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random):

> The function when originally implemented in OpenBSD, used the RC4
>   cipher to produce the output stream. OpenBSD now uses a ChaCha20
>   stream cipher.

and

> RC4 has been designed by RSA Data Security, Inc.  It was posted anonymously
>   to the USENET and was confirmed to be equivalent by   several
>   sources who had access to the original cipher.  Since RC4 used to be a
>   trade secret, the cipher is now referred to as ARC4.

---

It is important to understand what is the difference between the two class of pseudorandom number generators.

A **PRNG** is designed for purposes where all you care about is (ideally) high amount of statistical randomness: fields where you want simulate randomness.

A **CSPRNG** is designed for purposes where the latter is simply not enough, but high amount of unpredictability (even when the generator algorithm is exactly known) is also required: the field of cryptography.

So you don't need a CSPRNG to generate numbers with high quality of statistical randomness. All you need is a high quality PRNG. `rand()` is nowhere to that and `arc4random()` is an overshoot.

See [this](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/) page for simple, modern, high quality random number generators.

Comment: This is a great answer. It turns out even a fixed random sequence is good enough. So absolutely no need for arc4random.

Comment: I mean the same sequence hard coded in the game is good enough. So it is like using rand without srand. :-)

Comment: @ZhigangAn If you want you can seed `rand()` with some type of hardware entropy like `std::time()` or `std::clock()`. So the sequence will be different each time you run the program.